# Is it possible to create a 'wait until loop' and keep other code running at the same time as this loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, wait

Is it possible to create a 'wait until loop' and keep other code running at the same time as this loop in JavaScript? I know that while loops don't work.

Comment: You generally don't need it. If you're waiting on something asynchronous like a network response, you'll have a callback or a promise. If it's synchronous, you can just act when you set whatever value you're waiting for. Maybe you can add some details to the question for a more detailed response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. However, from what I understand, you are talking about asynchronous tasks. 
Please check the mdn documentation for setTimer() and setInterval().